# Google Rich Snippets & Google Structured Data Tester

Tags: javascript, google-search-console, google-rich-snippets

We've been trying to get Google Rich Snippets working on the site for months now. We fixed some JavaScript errors a while back that were definitely contributing to the problem, but going on 12 weeks later still no joy. When I use Google's Structured Data Tester no errors are found, but there are various "Unspecified type" messages on each page (see screenshot).  [image: Google Structured Data Tester output]
[Google Structured Data Tester](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.northshorecare.com%252Fbrowse-brands%252Fnorthshore-brands%252Fnorthshore-magicsorb-disposable-underpads.html)

My question: does anyone know if this could be contributing to the Google Rich Snippets not working correctly? I've basically exhausted every other possibility and holding out for divine intervention at this point....

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

The structured data testing tool is now used to test rich snippets, so yes that is what you need to fix. From your link it appears that the errors come from 4 hyperlinks which is all outside the scope of the http://schema.org/Product and http://schema.org/Offer - the `<div>` and `<form>` tags end *before* them.

If this answer isn't enough for you to work from then can you explain what these 4 links mean? I can't give you what the code should be because it's unclear what these 4 links are for and where the should be in the structured data. Are they similar products? And they multiple offers for the same product?

Comment: The four "unspecified type" links are to images that appear on the product description page on a Magento site for that particular product. Is there some way to connect the dots and associate those images with the product so they're no longer "unspecified type(s)" 

The PDP page: http://www.northshorecare.com/browse-brands/northshore-brands/northshore-magicsorb-disposable-underpads.html

Comment: Once you sort out the itemscope issue so that the <div> or other tag for http://schema.org/Product has the image nested inside it, all you need to do it as the **image** property to the `<img>` tag using `itemprop` - start with `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">MagicSorb` then add: `<img itemprop="image" src="http://www.northshorecare.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/64x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/n/s/nsc-magicsorb.jpg" alt="MagicSorb Disposable Underpad" />` and anything else then close div `</div>`
Multiple images are allowed for the same product.

Comment: So take this content: https://jsbin.com/yeketa/edit?html,output and convert it to this? https://jsbin.com/copono/edit?html,output by adding itemscope and itemtype to the img tags?

Comment: I can't see the code in your links. All you do is add **itemprop=image** inside the `<img> tags. No need for the `itemscope itemtype=` unless you want to add more information about the image.